# Replication Monitor Information using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2005, merge-replication, transactional-replication

The image below shows a transaction replication problem that I am currently investigating.

The image comes from the Replication Monitor.

How can I get this information using T-SQL?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After doing some online search,I found what you needed,hope my answer helps you.

**Answer 1**

Note:

> It Only works with transactional and transactional peer to peer
>   replication

### T-SQL script which you can use to monitor the status of transactional replication and performance of publications and subscriptions.

**Things to be considered before executing the below script**

*Requires permission on the following tables inside distribution and master databases*

- MSdistribution_status
- MSdistribution_agents
- MSArticles
- MSreplication_monitordata
- MSdistribution_history
- servers

---

```
    USE [distribution]

    IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb.dbo.#ReplStats') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP TABLE #ReplStats 

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#ReplStats](
    [DistributionAgentName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [DistributionAgentStartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DistributionAgentRunningDurationInSeconds] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsAgentRunning] [bit] NULL,
    [ReplicationStatus] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [LastSynchronized] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Comments] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Publisher] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [PublicationName] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [PublisherDB] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [Subscriber] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [SubscriberDB] [sysname] NULL,
    [SubscriptionType] [varchar](64) NULL,
    [DistributionDB] [sysname] NULL,
    [Article] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [UndelivCmdsInDistDB] [int] NULL,
    [DelivCmdsInDistDB] [int] NULL,
    [CurrentSessionDeliveryRate] [float] NOT NULL,
    [CurrentSessionDeliveryLatency] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotalTransactionsDeliveredInCurrentSession] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotalCommandsDeliveredInCurrentSession] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AverageCommandsDeliveredInCurrentSession] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryRate] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryLatency] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotalCommandsDeliveredSinceSubscriptionSetup] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNumber] [varbinary](16) NULL,
    [LastDistributerSync] [datetime] NULL,
    [Retention] [int] NULL,
    [WorstLatency] [int] NULL,
    [BestLatency] [int] NULL,
    [AverageLatency] [int] NULL,
    [CurrentLatency] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]


    INSERT INTO #ReplStats 
    SELECT da.[name] AS [DistributionAgentName]
    ,dh.[start_time] AS [DistributionAgentStartTime]
    ,dh.[duration] AS [DistributionAgentRunningDurationInSeconds]
    ,md.[isagentrunningnow] AS [IsAgentRunning]
    ,CASE md.[status]
    WHEN 1 THEN '1 - Started'
    WHEN 2 THEN '2 - Succeeded'
    WHEN 3 THEN '3 - InProgress'
    WHEN 4 THEN '4 - Idle'
    WHEN 5 THEN '5 - Retrying'
    WHEN 6 THEN '6 - Failed'
    END AS [ReplicationStatus]
    ,dh.[time] AS [LastSynchronized]
    ,dh.[comments] AS [Comments]
    ,md.[publisher] AS [Publisher]
    ,da.[publication] AS [PublicationName]
    ,da.[publisher_db] AS [PublisherDB]
    ,CASE 
    WHEN da.[anonymous_subid] IS NOT NULL 
    THEN UPPER(da.[subscriber_name])
    ELSE UPPER (s.[name]) END AS [Subscriber]
    ,da.[subscriber_db] AS [SubscriberDB]
    ,CASE da.[subscription_type]
    WHEN '0' THEN 'Push'  
    WHEN '1' THEN 'Pull'  
    WHEN '2' THEN 'Anonymous'  
    ELSE CAST(da.[subscription_type] AS [varchar](64)) END AS [SubscriptionType]
    ,md.[distdb] AS [DistributionDB]
    ,ma.[article]    AS [Article]
    ,ds.[UndelivCmdsInDistDB] 
    ,ds.[DelivCmdsInDistDB]
    ,dh.[current_delivery_rate] AS [CurrentSessionDeliveryRate]
    ,dh.[current_delivery_latency] AS [CurrentSessionDeliveryLatency]
    ,dh.[delivered_transactions] AS [TotalTransactionsDeliveredInCurrentSession]
    ,dh.[delivered_commands] AS [TotalCommandsDeliveredInCurrentSession]
    ,dh.[average_commands] AS [AverageCommandsDeliveredInCurrentSession]
    ,dh.[delivery_rate] AS [DeliveryRate]
    ,dh.[delivery_latency] AS [DeliveryLatency]
    ,dh.[total_delivered_commands] AS [TotalCommandsDeliveredSinceSubscriptionSetup]
    ,dh.[xact_seqno] AS [SequenceNumber]
    ,md.[last_distsync] AS [LastDistributerSync]
    ,md.[retention] AS [Retention]
    ,md.[worst_latency] AS [WorstLatency]
    ,md.[best_latency] AS [BestLatency]
    ,md.[avg_latency] AS [AverageLatency]
    ,md.[cur_latency] AS [CurrentLatency]
    FROM [distribution]..[MSdistribution_status] ds 
    INNER JOIN [distribution]..[MSdistribution_agents] da
    ON da.[id] = ds.[agent_id]                          
    INNER JOIN [distribution]..[MSArticles] ma 
    ON ma.publisher_id = da.publisher_id 
    AND ma.[article_id] = ds.[article_id]
    INNER JOIN [distribution]..[MSreplication_monitordata] md
    ON [md].[job_id] = da.[job_id]
    INNER JOIN [distribution]..[MSdistribution_history] dh
    ON [dh].[agent_id] = md.[agent_id] 
    AND md.[agent_type] = 3
    INNER JOIN [master].[sys].[servers]  s
    ON s.[server_id] = da.[subscriber_id] 
    --Created WHEN your publication has the immediate_sync property set to true. This property dictates 
    --whether snapshot is available all the time for new subscriptions to be initialized. 
    --This affects the cleanup behavior of transactional replication. If this property is set to true, 
    --the transactions will be retained for max retention period instead of it getting cleaned up
    --as soon as all the subscriptions got the change. 
    WHERE da.[subscriber_db] <> 'virtual' 
    AND da.[anonymous_subid] IS NULL
    AND dh.[start_time] = (SELECT TOP 1 start_time
                    FROM [distribution]..[MSdistribution_history] a
                    JOIN [distribution]..[MSdistribution_agents] b
                    ON a.[agent_id] = b.[id] AND b.[subscriber_db] <> 'virtual'
                    WHERE [runstatus] <> 1
                    ORDER BY [start_time] DESC)
    AND dh.[runstatus] <> 1

    SELECT 'Transactional Replication Summary' AS [Comments];
    SELECT [DistributionAgentName]
    ,[DistributionAgentStartTime]
    ,[DistributionAgentRunningDurationInSeconds]
    ,[IsAgentRunning]
    ,[ReplicationStatus]
    ,[LastSynchronized]
    ,[Comments]
    ,[Publisher]
    ,[PublicationName]
    ,[PublisherDB]
    ,[Subscriber]
    ,[SubscriberDB]
    ,[SubscriptionType]
    ,[DistributionDB]
    ,SUM([UndelivCmdsInDistDB]) AS [UndelivCmdsInDistDB]
    ,SUM([DelivCmdsInDistDB]) AS [DelivCmdsInDistDB]
    ,[CurrentSessionDeliveryRate]
    ,[CurrentSessionDeliveryLatency]
    ,[TotalTransactionsDeliveredInCurrentSession]
    ,[TotalCommandsDeliveredInCurrentSession]
    ,[AverageCommandsDeliveredInCurrentSession]
    ,[DeliveryRate]
    ,[DeliveryLatency]
    ,[TotalCommandsDeliveredSinceSubscriptionSetup]
    ,[SequenceNumber]
    ,[LastDistributerSync]
    ,[Retention]
    ,[WorstLatency]
    ,[BestLatency]
    ,[AverageLatency]
    ,[CurrentLatency]
    FROM #ReplStats
    GROUP BY [DistributionAgentName]
    ,[DistributionAgentStartTime]
    ,[DistributionAgentRunningDurationInSeconds]
    ,[IsAgentRunning]
    ,[ReplicationStatus]
    ,[LastSynchronized]
    ,[Comments]
    ,[Publisher]
    ,[PublicationName]
    ,[PublisherDB]
    ,[Subscriber]
    ,[SubscriberDB]
    ,[SubscriptionType]
    ,[DistributionDB]
    ,[CurrentSessionDeliveryRate]
    ,[CurrentSessionDeliveryLatency]
    ,[TotalTransactionsDeliveredInCurrentSession]
    ,[TotalCommandsDeliveredInCurrentSession]
    ,[AverageCommandsDeliveredInCurrentSession]
    ,[DeliveryRate]
    ,[DeliveryLatency]
    ,[TotalCommandsDeliveredSinceSubscriptionSetup]
    ,[SequenceNumber]
    ,[LastDistributerSync]
    ,[Retention]
    ,[WorstLatency]
    ,[BestLatency]
    ,[AverageLatency]
    ,[CurrentLatency]

    SELECT 'Transactional Replication Summary Details' AS [Comments];
    SELECT [Publisher]
    ,[PublicationName]
    ,[PublisherDB]
    ,[Article]
    ,[Subscriber]
    ,[SubscriberDB]
    ,[SubscriptionType]
    ,[DistributionDB]
    ,SUM([UndelivCmdsInDistDB]) AS [UndelivCmdsInDistDB]
    ,SUM([DelivCmdsInDistDB]) AS [DelivCmdsInDistDB]
    FROM #ReplStats
    GROUP BY [Publisher]
    ,[PublicationName]
    ,[PublisherDB]
    ,[Article]
    ,[Subscriber]
    ,[SubscriberDB]
    ,[SubscriptionType]
    ,[DistributionDB]
```

---

**Answer 2**

**Script_2** found on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6f54ddd9-3dee-4eea-9dcf-589dd79e18a0/push-and-pull-transaction-replication?forum=sqlreplication)

```
    --First you find the distributor servername using the below running in publisher
    Use master
    EXEC sp_helpdistributor;

    --Then you can run the below to find the type (use distributor database)

    SELECT 
    (CASE  
    WHEN mdh.runstatus =  '1' THEN 'Start - '+cast(mdh.runstatus as varchar)
    WHEN mdh.runstatus =  '2' THEN 'Succeed - '+cast(mdh.runstatus as varchar)
    WHEN mdh.runstatus =  '3' THEN 'InProgress - '+cast(mdh.runstatus as varchar)
    WHEN mdh.runstatus =  '4' THEN 'Idle - '+cast(mdh.runstatus as varchar)
    WHEN mdh.runstatus =  '5' THEN 'Retry - '+cast(mdh.runstatus as varchar)
    WHEN mdh.runstatus =  '6' THEN 'Fail - '+cast(mdh.runstatus as varchar)
    ELSE CAST(mdh.runstatus AS VARCHAR)
    END) [Run Status], 
    mda.subscriber_db [Subscriber DB], 
    mda.publication [PUB Name],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),mdh.[time]) [LastSynchronized],
    und.UndelivCmdsInDistDB [UndistCom], 
    mdh.comments [Comments], 
    'select * from distribution.dbo.msrepl_errors (nolock) where id = ' + CAST(mdh.error_id AS VARCHAR(8)) [Query More Info],
    mdh.xact_seqno [SEQ_NO],
    (CASE  
    WHEN mda.subscription_type =  '0' THEN 'Push' 
    WHEN mda.subscription_type =  '1' THEN 'Pull' 
    WHEN mda.subscription_type =  '2' THEN 'Anonymous' 
    ELSE CAST(mda.subscription_type AS VARCHAR)
    END) [SUB Type],

    mda.publisher_db+' - '+CAST(mda.publisher_database_id as varchar) [Publisher DB],
    mda.name [Pub - DB - Publication - SUB - AgentID]
    FROM distribution.dbo.MSdistribution_agents mda 
    LEFT JOIN distribution.dbo.MSdistribution_history mdh ON mdh.agent_id = mda.id 
    JOIN 
    (SELECT s.agent_id, MaxAgentValue.[time], SUM(CASE WHEN xact_seqno > MaxAgentValue.maxseq THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UndelivCmdsInDistDB 
    FROM distribution.dbo.MSrepl_commands t (NOLOCK)  
    JOIN distribution.dbo.MSsubscriptions AS s (NOLOCK) ON (t.article_id = s.article_id AND t.publisher_database_id=s.publisher_database_id ) 
    JOIN 
    (SELECT hist.agent_id, MAX(hist.[time]) AS [time], h.maxseq  
    FROM distribution.dbo.MSdistribution_history hist (NOLOCK) 
    JOIN (SELECT agent_id,ISNULL(MAX(xact_seqno),0x0) AS maxseq 
    FROM distribution.dbo.MSdistribution_history (NOLOCK)  
    GROUP BY agent_id) AS h  
    ON (hist.agent_id=h.agent_id AND h.maxseq=hist.xact_seqno) 
    GROUP BY hist.agent_id, h.maxseq 
    ) AS MaxAgentValue 
    ON MaxAgentValue.agent_id = s.agent_id 
    GROUP BY s.agent_id, MaxAgentValue.[time] 
    ) und 
    ON mda.id = und.agent_id AND und.[time] = mdh.[time] 
    where mda.subscriber_db<>'virtual' -- created when your publication has the immediate_sync property set to true. This property dictates whether snapshot is available all the time for new subscriptions to be initialized. This affects the cleanup behavior of transactional replication. If this property is set to true, the transactions will be retained for max retention period instead of it getting cleaned up as soon as all the subscriptions got the change.
    --and mdh.runstatus='6' --Fail
    --and mdh.runstatus<>'2' --Succeed
    order by mdh.[time]
```

---

Answer 3

Script featured on [SimpleTalk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/monitoring-transactional-replication-in-sql-server/) TSQL as an agent job.

### Step 1

Create in a DBA database installed on the subscriber server. The code to create the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Replication_Qu_History(
            Subscriber_db varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            Records_In_Que numeric(18, 0) NULL,
            CatchUpTime numeric(18, 0) NULL,
            LogDate datetime NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_EPR_Replication_Que_History PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
            Subscriber_db ASC, LogDate DESC
    ) ON PRIMARY
    GO
```

Script 1

The data in this table is populated by the monitoring procedures and provides an historical context for examining issues.  But to monitor what is happening right now more is required.

There are three things that help to determine the health of replication.

- The status of the replication related jobs
- The latency (especially the distribution latency) as measured by the
  counter Dist:Delivery Latency
- The number of outstanding commands that are pending for the
  subscription

  ```
  DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(max)
  DECLARE @publisher SYSNAME, @publisher_db SYSNAME, @publication SYSNAME, @pubtype INT
  DECLARE @subscriber SYSNAME, @subscriber_db SYSNAME, @subtype INT
  DECLARE @cmdcount INT, @processtime INT
  DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
  DECLARE @JobName SYSNAME
  DECLARE @minutes INT, @threshold INT, @maxCommands INT, @mail CHAR(1) = 'N'
  SET @minutes = 60 --> Define how many minutes latency before you would like to be notified
  SET @maxCommands = 80000  --->  change this to represent the max number of outstanding commands to be proceduresed before notification
  SET @threshold = @minutes * 60

  SELECT * INTO #PublisherInfo
  FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 'SERVER=(LOCAL);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;'
  , 'SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC distribution.dbo.sp_replmonitorhelppublisher')

  SELECT @publisher = publisher FROM #PublisherInfo     

  SET @cmd = 'SELECT * INTO ##PublicationInfo FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'',''SERVER=(LOCAL);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES''
  ,''SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC distribution.dbo.sp_replmonitorhelppublication @publisher='
  + @publisher + ''')'
  --select @cmd
  EXEC sp_executesql @cmd

  SELECT @publisher_db=publisher_db, @publication=publication, @pubtype=publication_type  FROM ##PublicationInfo

  SET @cmd = 'SELECT * INTO ##SubscriptionInfo FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'',''SERVER=(LOCAL);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES''
  ,''SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC distribution.dbo.sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription @publisher='
  + @publisher + ',@publication_type=' + CONVERT(CHAR(1),@pubtype) + ''')'
  --select @cmd
  EXEC sp_executesql @cmd


  ALTER TABLE ##SubscriptionInfo
  ADD  PendingCmdCount INT NULL,
  EstimatedProcessTime INT NULL
  ```

  To check the status of the distribution jobs

  ```
  DECLARE cur_sub CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
  SELECT @publisher, s.publisher_db, s.publication, s.subscriber, s.subscriber_db, s.subtype, s.distribution_agentname
  FROM ##SubscriptionInfo s

  OPEN cur_sub  
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur_sub INTO @publisher, @publisher_db, @publication, @subscriber, @subscriber_db, @subtype, @JobName

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
  BEGIN  
  SET @cmd = 'SELECT @cmdcount=pendingcmdcount, @processtime=estimatedprocesstime FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'',''SERVER=(LOCAL);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES''
  ,''SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC distribution.dbo.sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds @publisher=' + @publisher
  + ',@publisher_db=' + @publisher_db + ',@publication=' + @publication
  + ',@subscriber=' + @subscriber + ',@subscriber_db=' + @subscriber_db
  + ',@subscription_type=' + CONVERT(CHAR(1),@subtype) + ';' + ''')'
  SET @ParmDefinition = N'@cmdcount INT OUTPUT,
  @processtime INT OUTPUT'
  --select @cmd
  EXEC sp_executesql @cmd,@ParmDefinition,@cmdcount OUTPUT, @processtime OUTPUT

  UPDATE ##SubscriptionInfo
  SET PendingCmdCount = @cmdcount
  , EstimatedProcessTime = @processtime
  WHERE subscriber_db = @subscriber_db

  INSERT INTO DBA.dbo.Replication_Que_History
  VALUES(@subscriber_db, @cmdcount, @processtime, GETDATE())
  --  find out if the distribution job with the high number of outstanding commands running or not
  --  if it is running then sometimes stopping and starting the agent fixes the issue
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '##JobInfo%')
  DROP TABLE ##JobInfo

  SET @cmd = 'SELECT * INTO ##JobInfo FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'',''SERVER=(LOCAL);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES''
  ,''SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @job_name='''''
  + @JobName + ''''',@job_aspect=''''JOB'''''')'
  EXEC sp_executesql @cmd

  IF @cmdcount > @maxCommands OR (@processtime > @threshold AND @cmdcount > 0)
  BEGIN
  IF (SELECT current_execution_status FROM ##JobInfo) = 1 --  This means job is currently executing so stop/start it
  BEGIN
  EXEC distribution.dbo.sp_MSstopdistribution_agent
  @publisher = @publisher
  , @publisher_db = @publisher_db
  , @publication = @publication
  , @subscriber = @subscriber
  , @subscriber_db = @subscriber_db
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' ---- 5 Second Delay
  SET @mail = 'Y' 
  END
  END   
  --SELECT name, current_execution_status FROM ##JobInfo
  IF (SELECT current_execution_status FROM ##JobInfo) <> 1 -- if the job is not running start it
  BEGIN
  EXEC distribution.dbo.sp_MSstartdistribution_agent
  @publisher = @publisher
  , @publisher_db = @publisher_db
  , @publication = @publication
  , @subscriber = @subscriber
  , @subscriber_db = @subscriber_db
  SET @mail = 'Y'      -- Send email if job has stopped and needed to be restarted
  END   
  DROP TABLE ##JobInfo
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur_sub INTO @publisher, @publisher_db, @publication, @subscriber, @subscriber_db, @subtype, @JobName
  END  

  CLOSE cur_sub  
  DEALLOCATE cur_sub
  ```

  Run the Microsoft-supplied procedure `sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds`

  ```
  --system stored procedure to run in distribution database
  execute sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds
  --replication publisher server
  @publisher ='PubServer',
  --replication publisher database
  @publisher_db = 'ProdDBPub',
  --replication publication name
  @publication ='ProdDBSub',
  --replication subscriber server
  @subscriber ='SubServer',
  --replication subscriber database
  @subscriber_db ='ProdDBSub1',
  --choose type of subscription you have
  @subscription_type ='1' --0 for push and 1 for pull
  GO
  ```

The code below requires the Ad Hoc Distributed Queries server configuration option be enabled. Here I create the email to be sent assuming the previous Script 3 found an issue `sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds` .

```
        IF @mail = 'Y'
        BEGIN
        DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Replication on ' + @@SERVERNAME
        + ' may be experiencing some problems.  Attempts to restart the distribution agent have been made. '
        + 'If this is not the first message like this that you have received within the last hour, please investigate.'
        DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @xml1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @tab1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @xml2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @tab2 NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @xml1 = CAST(( SELECT subscriber AS 'td','',subscriber_db AS 'td','',
        latency AS 'td','', PendingCmdCount AS 'td','', EstimatedProcessTime AS 'td'
        FROM  ##SubscriptionInfo s
        FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

        SET @tab1 ='<html><body><H4>Subscription Information </H4>
        <table border = 1> <tr>
        <th> Subscriber </th> <th> Subscriber Database </th> <th> Latency(seconds)</th>
        <th> Undistributed Commands </th> <th> Estimated Catch Up Time</th></tr>'   
        --  this command gives us the last 10 measurements of latency for each subscriber
        SET @xml2 = CAST(( SELECT s.Subscriber_db AS 'td','', s.Records_In_Que AS 'td','', s.CatchUpTime AS 'td','', CONVERT(CHAR(22),LogDate, 100) AS 'td'
        FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY subscriber_db ORDER BY Logdate DESC ) AS 'RowNumber',
        subscriber_db
        , Records_In_Que
        , CatchUpTime
        , Logdate
        FROM DBA.dbo.Replication_Que_History
        ) s
        WHERE RowNumber <= 8
        FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

        SET @tab2 ='<br><br><H4>Historical Latency Information </H4>
        <table border = 1>
        <tr>
        <th>Subscriber</th> <th>Undistributed Commands</th> <th> Catch Up Time </th> <th> Date\Time </th></tr>'

        SET @body = @msg + @tab1 + @xml1 + '</table>'
        + @tab2 + @xml2 + '</body></html>'

        DECLARE @to NVARCHAR(200)
        SELECT @to = '' -- INSERT YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS HERE
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @body = @body,
        @body_format ='HTML',
        @recipients = @to,
        @subject = 'Possible Replication Problem' ;
        END
        DROP TABLE #PublisherInfo
        DROP TABLE ##PublicationInfo
        DROP TABLE ##SubscriptionInfo
```

Last process is to periodically delete rows from the replication status table so the data does not get stale

```
DECLARE @delDate datetime = getdate()-10
  DELETE FROM DBA.dbo.Replication_Que_History
  WHERE LogDate < @deldate
```

Pls also consider I also noted that 
There is an issue with sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds if you are still with SQL Server 2005 and 2008 [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/507595/sp-replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds)

**If any of the above answer are unclear you can follow the source I have provided**

Thanks!

Comment: this is gold man!!! wonderful!

Comment: @marcelomiorelli No prb & Thanks! Because this community is always about helping each other :)

Comment: I dont know why this only has one upvote, have more.

Answer (score 4):

You can get information you need by querying the dbo.MSReplication_monitordata table from a distribution database with this script, for all publications:

```
USE distribution
SELECT status AS ReplicationAgentsStatus 
FROM dbo.MSReplication_monitordata
WHERE publication = 'ALL'
```

For particular publication, modify 'ALL' in WHERE statement

Also, you can use this powershell script to filter the status column from system stored procedure sp_replmonitorhelppublication:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "USE distribution
EXEC sp_replmonitorhelppublication" -ServerInstance "TIKVICKI" | Out-File d:\temp1.txt


Get-Content d:\temp1.txt | where { $_.Contains("status : ") } | 
out-file d:\temp2.txt


(Get-Content d:\temp2.txt).replace('status ', 'Replication agents 
status') | 
Set-Content d:\Replication_Agents_Status_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss).txt

Remove-Item d:\temp1.txt -Force
Remove-Item d:\temp2.txt -Force
```

I found this scripts in [this](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-monitor-sql-server-replication-agents-status/) article, which also describes how to do this through UI with either third party [tool](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_monitor.aspx) or SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

There's [a stored procedure that may help you,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186304.aspx) but *permuting* the results of a stored procedure [are kludgy,](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) as you may know.

```
sp_replmonitorhelppublication null
```