# How to completely get rid of replication subscriptions?

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have restored a database in another server. I don't want any of the transactional subscriptions of the former database.  I already called

```
exec sp_removedbreplication 'MyRestoredDB' 
go
```

And also

```
exec sp_cleanupdbreplication
go
```

And

```
exec sp_replicationdboption 'MyRestoredDB','Publish','False',1
go
```

But when I try

```
truncate table dbo.sample
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 4711, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 Cannot truncate table 'sample'
>   because it is published for replication or enabled for Change Data
>   Capture.

I verified that the database isn't enabled for CDC.  What else I can do to perform the truncate?  Delete isn't an option for reasons not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2710/steps-to-clean-up-orphaned-replication-settings-in-sql-server/

Try dropping the old subscriptions, all publications and then removing replication from the DB, i.e.

```
exec sp_dropsubscription --on all subscriptions
```

then

```
exec sp_droppublication --on all publications
```

then

```
exec sp_replicationdboption
```

Also, take a look at this question: [How to fix a messed up replication on MS SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135745/how-to-fix-a-messed-up-replication-on-ms-sql-server/177383)

Comment: sp_removedbreplication  already dropped all my subscriptions.  I don't have any publications in the target server.  However, SQL Server still thinks the table is being replicated.