# Replication fails with "Transaction log for database is full due to LOG_BACKUP"

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, transaction-log, transactional-replication

Replication is failing with the subject error.

The `log_reuse_wait_desc` states `LOG_BACKUP`.

I have performed both database and log backups.

After changing the recovery mode to single, performing backup, and then changing recovery mode back to FULL, `log_reuse_wait_desc` goes to `NOTHING`.

As soon as I start the replication jobs they fail with the subject error.

I did shrink on log file to no avail.  Any suggestions to resolve this?

Comment: Which database is being reported as having a full transaction log, the publisher, subscriber or distribution database?

Comment: Also, shrinking the log files makes it worse. You make the "bucket" for your log records smaller, causing it to become full sooner.

Comment: The Publisher database log is full

Answer (score 1):

there is no clear indication of what may be causing this upsetting in the transaction log.

but I would check it out what is happening in the `distribution`.

run the following procedure:

```
sp_helpdistributor
```

that will show you where the distribution database and server is.

Assuming the name of the distribution database is `distribution`:

```
 SELECT * FROM distribution.dbo.MSrepl_Commands
```

have a look at what you get and use the last transaction to see what is in it:

[image]

check it out:

```
 SELECT * FROM distribution.dbo.MSrepl_Commands 
--- commands for all transactions for replication for seqno or all
  WHERE   xact_seqno = 0x000002470000F7D30021
```

if all good or at least nothing obviously bad:
use that xact_seqno here (I did not use the end one on this example - but if your replication is very busy you can limit it):

```
    exec distribution.dbo.sp_browsereplcmds @xact_seqno_start =  '0x000002470000F7D30021',  -- returns all/seqno info (sql query) on replication
   -- @xact_seqno_end  =  '0x00001C030000F4540018'
```

This allows you to see what has been replicated - what commands to each article (see on the right hand side of the picture below)

[image]

This is not a comprehensive answer but would give you a start.
Well after the obvious thing as looking at the [replication monitor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/237146/22336).

Check [these scripts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/88938/22336) to give you some extra vision.

You can also check [Some useful commands and sp for Transaction Replication](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/some-useful-commands-and-sp-for-transaction-replication)