# Is there any way to monitor if all columns in an article is published in replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, t-sql

In replication, if we add a column in Publisher then it doesnt replicate to Subscriber unless it is done explicitly. I am looking for a way to track or monitor this.
I am not able to find any system stored procedure which I can use to compare the columns and if they are replicated between Publisher and Subscriber.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community. Maybe the answer in that question will help. [Replication Monitor Information using T-SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88923/replication-monitor-information-using-t-sql)

Comment: Is DDL replication enabled in the publication?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access right now to a replicated instance to verify but I believe the system tables and DMVs should help.

[sys.dm_repl_schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-repl-schemas-transact-sql) "Returns information about table columns published by replication." Those will be the ones currently in the published article.

[sys.columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql) will list all the columns in the source table. (You can join to sys.objects or use OBJECT_NAME() to get the table; similarly for the schema.)

By comparing those two lists you'll know which columns have been added to the base table without being included in the replication article.