# what is stopping my transactional replication services?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication, dmv, error-log

I will be straightforward and put my question before I add any other information, as I want to keep it objective and to the point.

the question is:

**How to find out why the replication services are stopping?**

I thought that [this info would be stored in the distribution database like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/88923/22336):

```
select * from distribution.dbo.msrepl_errors (nolock) where id = 0
```

But this was not the case.

I am coming across some errors on my transactional replication.
that I could clearly see:

[image]

> Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc  Target Site: Void
> FilterException(System.Exception)  Message: Exception of type
> 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.  Stack:    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.EnumeratorException.FilterException(Exception
> e)     at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object
> connectionInfo, Request request)     at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.GetEnumeratorData(Request
> req)     at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetDbCollation(String
> dbname)     at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetDbComparer(Boolean
> inServer)     at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.InitializeStringComparer()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.AbstractCollectionBase.get_StringComparer()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SimpleObjectCollectionBase.InitInnerCollection()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.GetObjectByKey(ObjectKeyBase
> key)     at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseCollection.get_Item(String
> name)     at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SmoScriptingManager.PrefetchObjects(ObjectPrefetchControl[]
> objectPrefetchControls)     at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SmoScriptingManager.DoPrefetchWithRetry()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SmoScriptingManager.DoScripting()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.DoScripting()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.GenerateSnapshot()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.SnapshotGenerationAgent.InternalRun()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.Run()

while running a snapshot:

> memory mapped file write failed

and previous to that:

> System.OutOfMemoryException

[image]

and also a few of these:

> Error messages: The replication agent has not logged a progress
> message in 10 minutes. This might indicate an unresponsive agent or
> high system activity. Verify that records are being replicated to the
> destination and that connections to the Subscriber, Publisher, and
> Distributor are still active.

[image]

> Error messages: ⦁ Message: memory mapped file write failed Stack:
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServer.NativeBcpOutProvider.ThrowNativeBcpOutException(CConnection*
> pNativeConnectionWrapper)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServer.NativeBcpOutProvider.BcpOut(String
> strBcpObjectName, String strBcpObjectOwner, String
> strBaseBcpObjectName, Boolean fUnicodeConversion, String strDataFile,
> String strLoadOrderingHint, String strWhereClause, Boolean
> useTableLockHint, Int32 bcpFileFormatVersion)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServer.BcpOutThreadProvider.DoWork(WorkItem
> workItem)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.WorkerThread.NonExceptionBasedAgentThreadProc()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.BaseAgentThread.AgentThreadProcWrapper()
> (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 0) Get help: http://help/0

and the previous error message:

> Error messages: ⦁ Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
> Target Site: Void FilterException(System.Exception) Message: Exception
> of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. Stack:    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.EnumeratorException.FilterException(Exception
> e)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object
> connectionInfo, Request request)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.GetEnumeratorData(Request
> req)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetDbCollation(String
> dbname)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetDbComparer(Boolean
> inServer)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.InitializeStringComparer()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.AbstractCollectionBase.get_StringComparer()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SimpleObjectCollectionBase.InitInnerCollection()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.GetObjectByKey(ObjectKeyBase
> key)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseCollection.get_Item(String
> name)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SmoScriptingManager.PrefetchObjects(ObjectPrefetchControl[]
> objectPrefetchControls)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SmoScriptingManager.DoPrefetchWithRetry()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SmoScriptingManager.DoScripting()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.DoScripting()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.GenerateSnapshot()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.SnapshotGenerationAgent.InternalRun()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.Run() (Source:
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Error number: 0) Get help:
> http://help/0

and while troubleshooting it
it turned out that the computer is really out of memory

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of find out what exactly caused the services to stop I have created a job that will restart them services if they are not running.

[Simple script to check SQL Server Replication Jobs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4600/simple-script-to-check-sql-server-replication-jobs/)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetReplicationAgentStatus
AS

BEGIN
set nocount on
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted 

/*
Make sure your agents are in the correct category 
i.e Merge agents under REPL-Merge, 
Distribution agents under REPL-Distribution 
and LogReader agent under REPL-LogReader
*/

select s.job_id,s.name,s.enabled,c.name as categoryname into #JobList 
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs s inner join msdb.dbo.syscategories c on s.category_id = c.category_id
where c.name in ('REPL-Merge','REPL-Distribution','REPL-LogReader')

create TABLE #xp_results  
   (job_id                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    last_run_date         INT              NOT NULL,
    last_run_time         INT              NOT NULL,
    next_run_date         INT              NOT NULL,
    next_run_time         INT              NOT NULL,
    next_run_schedule_id  INT              NOT NULL,
    requested_to_run      INT              NOT NULL, 
    request_source        INT              NOT NULL,
    request_source_id     sysname          COLLATE database_default NULL,
    running               INT              NOT NULL,
    current_step          INT              NOT NULL,
    current_retry_attempt INT              NOT NULL,
    job_state             INT              NOT NULL)

insert into #xp_results 
exec master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, ''

select j.name,j.categoryname,j.enabled, AgentStatus = 
        CASE WHEN r.running =1 THEN 'Running' else 'Stopped'   end
from #JobList j inner join #xp_results r on j.job_id=r.job_id

-- Uncomment the below portion and use correct parameters to send email alert
/*
if exists (select j.name,j.categoryname,j.enabled,r.running
from #JobList j inner join #xp_results r   
on j.job_id=r.job_id where running =0 )
begin
   declare @subject nvarchar(100)
   select @subject = N'Replication Agents Status on '+@@servername

   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'ProfileName',
      @recipients = N'email id',
      @subject = @subject,
      @body = 'One or more agents found stopped'
end
*/
drop table #JobList,#xp_results
END
```

this procedure above is wrapped in a job and scheduled to run every hour.

the little difference is I put everything into a temp table, and read it row by row
and start the jobs that are not running:

```
             Print @job_name +' is currently not running.'
             exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @Job_id = @job_id
```

Comment: That's cool and all, but if your machine really is running out of Memory (at the OS level), that sounds like the root problem you need to address. It sounds like Max Memory defined on the instance may be too high relative to how much Memory is installed on the server. But you may also need to add more Memory to the server too.

Comment: Absolutely! Has been addressed thank you